# Highlight text and have it read back to me in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, accessibility, text-to-speech, narrator

On my Mac, I can highlight text, hit a keyboard command, and it reads the selected text aloud. Is there an analogue for **Windows 7**? I've tried enabling Narrator... but it's overkill; it seems to read everything on the screen!

**So, in short, I want to be able to highlight text and have it read back to me in Windows 7.**

If Narrator isn't the right tool for this, can anyone recommend a third party alternative (preferably a free one)?

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/647652/is-there-any-tts-tool-for-windows-equal-to-voicedream-reader-ghostreadermac?rq=1

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/485318/how-to-tell-windows-8-narrator-to-read-only-the-selected-text

Comment: @techie007 Thanks... unfortunately, I need Windows 7 info.

Comment: It's still valid -- Head to the Microsoft link given in the answer, and pick Windows 7 instead of Windows 8. Beyond that, product recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: @techie007 Got it! As far as I can tell, however, there's nothing in there about selecting text and reading back.